# Some issue with localization in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, localization

my messages_en.properties:

```
title=Backpack Content
list.book=Book
list.water=Water
current.locale=Current locale
list.sweater=Sweater
list.cookies=Cookies
```

My configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplConf implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
}

@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver(){
    return new SessionLocaleResolver();
}



private LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor(){
    var loc = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();

    loc.setParamName("lang");
    return loc;
}

}
```

My document named "welcome ftlh"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<#import "/spring.ftl" as spring>
<h1> <@spring.message "title" /></h1>
<ul>
<li><@spring.message "list.cookies" /></li>
<li><@spring.message "list.sweater" /></li>
<li><@spring.message "list.book" /></li>
<li><@spring.message "list.water" /></li>
</ul>
<hr>
<p><@spring.message "current.locale" />: ${.locale}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/welcomePage")
public String hello(){
    return "welcome";
}
```

I searched localhost:1314/welcomePage  and also tried localhost:1314/welcomePage?lang=en-GB but it only showed:

> FreeMarker template error (DEBUG mode; use RETHROW in production!): Java method "org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getMessage(String)" threw an exception when invoked on org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext object "org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext@63511cca"; see cause exception in the Java stack trace. ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related): - Failed at: ${springMacroRequestContext.getMessag... [in template "spring.ftl" in macro "message" at line 28, column 22] - Reached through: @spring.message "title" [in template "welcome.ftlh" at line 9, column 6] ---- Java stack trace (for programmers): ---- freemarker.core._TemplateModelException: [... Exception message was already printed; see it above ...]

Comment: What happens if you try `<@spring.message code="title"  />` would that work?

Answer (score 1):

Configure application.yml

```
spring:
  messages:
    basename: org/springframework/security/messages, yourPath/messages
```